# Compilation error of test scripts from Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testing, automated-tests

Jenkins maven project shows *[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR* after step 
*--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile)*.
All selenium-elements are non-recognized. Also, there are rather strange slashes "/" instead of "\" in files paths.
If compilation starts through maven:surefire in IntelijIdea, such problems don't appear.

Here are links to Jenkins configure and pom.xml photos

[Jenkins conf1]https://prnt.sc/ox1wzb

[Jenkins conf2]https://prnt.sc/ox1yye

[pom1]https://prnt.sc/ox1xzg

[pom2]https://prnt.sc/ox2y21

What could be the mistake?

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/WebDriverSettings.java:[5,27] package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/WebDriverSettings.java:[6,27] package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/WebDriverSettings.java:[7,34] package org.openqa.selenium.chrome does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/WebDriverSettings.java:[8,35] package org.openqa.selenium.support does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/WebDriverSettings.java:[9,38] package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/WebDriverSettings.java:[13,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WebDriver
  location: class script_1_2_3.WebDriverSettings
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/WebDriverSettings.java:[14,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WebDriverWait
  location: class script_1_2_3.WebDriverSettings
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/PageObjects.java:[3,27] package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/PageObjects.java:[4,27] package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/PageObjects.java:[5,35] package org.openqa.selenium.support does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/PageObjects.java:[6,38] package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/ListsOperating.java:[3,27] package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/PageObjects.java:[12,71] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class script_1_2_3.PageObjects
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/PageObjects.java:[13,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class script_1_2_3.PageObjects
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/PageObjects.java:[14,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class script_1_2_3.PageObjects
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/PageObjects.java:[15,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class script_1_2_3.PageObjects
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/PageObjects.java:[16,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class script_1_2_3.PageObjects
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/PageObjects.java:[17,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class script_1_2_3.PageObjects
[ERROR] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/roz/src/test/java/script_1_2_3/PageObjects.java:[18,64] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class script_1_2_3.PageObjects
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is what the Java compiler cannot find classes that you refer. None of libraries that you defined in pom.xml contains `org.openqa.selenium`. Add Selenium library.

Also, before compiling on Jenkins, why have you not compiled it locally? It would be much easier to first make it compiling and running locally, and only then put it to Jenkins.

Comment: But their imports are defined in every needed classes in imports section. Local compiling is successful without defining such libraries in pom.

Comment: 1) Import only means, that this class needs corresponding package. But you have to provide this package to JVM. Otherwise JVM will not find it. 2) I believe you compile locally *not with Maven*. Or, it you compiled locally with Maven, then you use on Jenkins a pom.xml *different* from your local pom.xml. 3) Solution: Compile your code locally with maven. Fix compilation errors by adding missing libraries to pom.xml. After you fixed it locally, push your code to repository and only then start a job on Jenkins.

Comment: I compiled it in maven:surefire plugin. And pom.xml is sinchronizing through GitHub. But really, when i added selenium-java-client-driver, webdriver-htmlunit and selenium-support, almost errors are not showing. Now the problem is only with org.openqa.selenium. I cant find exactly such package. There are showing many different libraries in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openqa.selenium.

Comment: First look why have you imported this package. What class exactly you need from this package? When you know the class, look up for corresponding Selenium library that provides it.

Comment: But there may be many different import packages (if I understand correctly what you mean): org.openqa.selenium.By, org.openqa.selenium.WebElement,  org.openqa.selenium.Dimension, org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver... I must  correspond all them separately?

Comment: WebDriver is contained in the library org.openqa.selenium.webdriver/webdriver-common. Add it ot you pom.xml. Then check the next error, fix it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider three below things to solve this issue:

Jenkins:

Once You have Jenkins install, make sure you install Maven Plugins from “Manage Jenkins  Manage Plugins”
Then add the Simple New Item, As Maven Project.
Keep everything as it is, Add POM details under Build section.
You can set the Goals and Options as: clean install or test as well.

Java:

Check the JAVA_HOME file version and add the JDK version accordingly everywhere.

Maven:

Make sure you are using the right version of JDK or JRE for the compilation. (Common error of compilation come here)
In eclipse, go to “Window  Preference  Java  Installed JRE  Apply the JRE from Execution Environments”
Add Maven Compilation Plugins into POM.XML. o Make sure you have correct version of JDK

Below is the sample format.

[image]